# How to retrieve users via id array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have an array where I only have userIDs stored. How can I retrieve all users that match with the IDs in the array?

e.g.

```
myArray = ["12341234", "23452345", "34563456", ...];

Meteor.users.find({_id: ???})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator:

```
myArray = ["12341234", "23452345", "34563456", ...];

Meteor.users.find( { _id: { $in: myArray } } )
```